# Unable to install yarn on RHEL

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, rhel7

I have downloaded yarn yarn-1.7.0-1.noarch.rpm

when I run `sudo rpm --install yarn-1.7.0-1.noarch.rpm` I get the following error

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        nodejs is needed by yarn-1.7.0-1.noarch
```

If I run `node -v`

I get `v8.9.4`

I know node is installed anyway because we are already using it on this server for many microservices.

I am unable to use npm because I am behind a proxy and npm is now unusable with error 418 I am teapot

Comment: How was your new version of node installed? I suspect `yarn` is looking for the `rpm` version of node

Answer (score 0):

The Yarn package expects an RPM-packaged version of Nodejs (as mentioned by user3788685 in a comment). The Yarn docs [recommend](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#centos-stable) enabling both the yarn and nodejs repositories to satisfy this dependency:

```
curl --silent --location https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
sudo yum install yarn
```

Side note: It's always better to use the Yum package manager (`yum`) to install packages because it will handle dependencies for you and ensure that packages can be cleanly uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Specify the proxy server details to yum

- either in /etc/yum.conf :

> proxy=http://mycache.mydomain.com:3128
>
> proxy_username=yum-user
>
> proxy_password=qwerty

/!\ *however storing passwords is not safe, so you can use an authenticating proxy for this purpose*

- either at command line :

> http_proxy="http://yum-user:proxy-passwd@mycache.mydomain.com:3128" yum install mypackage

be sure to add a space as first character in command line to not have it stored in history (shell dependent i guess)

### 2. Or work offline

In case you need to work without network/ don't want to use proxy, i think you shall force installation of your package (yum option : --skip-broken) and them tell yarn to use your pre-installed nodejs :

```
PATH=/path/to/node/bin:$PATH yarn command
```